# Working with real-time data, bypassing CvloadImage

Tags: .net, opencv

This is how we display and process an Image  using Opencv:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( "MGC.jpg" );
    cvThreshold( img, img,  200, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY );
    cvNamedWindow( "Example1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cvShowImage("Example1", img);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage( &img );
    cvDestroyWindow( "Example1" );
    return 0;
}
```

Now can you help me to achieve my goal as outlined below:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    Some code here (using some API other than OpenCv).... // Captures a frame and  
    //streams the data into a buffer Buf
    Buffer B= Buf; // B contain binary image data i.e 16 bit pixel values
    cvThreshold( B, B,  200, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY );//Notice I am putting B and not an 
                                                     //Image(legal?)
    cvNamedWindow( "Example1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cvShowImage("Example1", B); //Notice I am putting B and not an Image(legal?)   
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage( &B );
    cvDestroyWindow( "Example1" );
    return 0;
}
```

Notice that I have not used any hard-disk read/write operation in the second code snippet, such as the following:

```
  IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( "MGC.jpg" );
```

Basically I am working with real-time scenario thus I am bypassing the time consuming `cvLoadImage`.  Obviously not saving the data into hard-disk, my entire data is still in the `Buffer B`. This save my time which is critical for my application.

**Note:** The fact is I will be doing more processing on the `Buffer B`, such as applying `cvminmaxloc` etc. *But all these functions require an Image loaded from disk, not a buffer such in my case.*

Can some point me to right direction to achieve my goal of working on Buffers instead of Images stored in the hard-disk? Am I committing some mistake in understanding the openCV functions?

**Update:**

A suggested below I can use `imdecode` for reading images from buffer. As explained above actually I will be doing processing on the image using OpenCv functions, for example `CVMinMaxLoc` and

```
 cvThreshold( src, src,  200, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY );
```

Now can I put `Buffer` as the first argument instead of Image in `cvThreshold( )`? If not then what is the alternative to dealing with `Buffers` (containing pixel values) with openCv functions? If there is no direct method to work with buffers, then what is the indirect method to achieve this goal? What is the work around?

In short I do not want to bring the data to hard disk before doing any processing.

Comment: Can't you convert your buffer to Opencv Mat or IplImage type buffer. Then rest of the opencv functions can work on buffers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understand that most of the C interface of OpenCV deals with `IplImage`, not `Buffer` nor any other custom data type. In other words, doing:

```
Buffer B = Buf; 
cvThreshold( B, B,  200, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY );
```

will issue a compiling error because `cvThreshold()` requires the data to be encapsulated in an `IplImage`.

I don't want to run the risk of being Captain Obvious, but you need to convert `Buffer` to `IplImage`. So how do you do that, one might ask. Well, `IplImage` is simple data type that holds these important pieces of information together:

- The **size** of the image (width/height);
- The **bit depth** of the image;
- The **number of channels**;
- And the **data** (pixels) of the image;

And [how do you create a `IplImage` from scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10125322/176769)? Call [`cvCreateImageHeader()`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/operations_on_arrays.html#createimageheader) followed by [`cvSetData()`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cvsetdata#cvSetData).

**Note**: for the *depth* parameter, you might want to use either [IPL_DEPTH_16U or IPL_DEPTH_16S](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/basic_structures.html#iplimage). If your image is RGB, the *number of channels* is 3. After you are done using the `IplImage`, don't forget to call `cvReleaseImage()` to free it's resources.

I believe the real challenge is: how will you extract all these information from `Buffer`. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There is [`imdecode`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imdecode) function in C++ OpenCV API which is able to decode image stored in memory buffer. But there are no analogs in legacy C API.

Comment: Thanks for the post. But how can I use some processing functions of OpenCV such as CvMinMaxloc after reading the the image using imdecode, b'çoz CVMinMaxLoc takes the first parameter as the image and not the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can put buffer (as you said having pixel values )in place of src i.e an Image loaded from disk in the following

```
  cvThreshold( src, src,  200, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY );
```

One way might be to convert your buffer in MAT and then use cvThreshold.

May be somebody having more experience might comment on this.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your buffer to the openCV type [Mat](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/core_basic_structures.html#cvmat)

Something similar is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734469/converting-basler-image-to-opencv)