# Iplimage to List<byte[]>

Tags: opencv, c++-cli

I am trying to pass a set of iplimage from OpenCV to another program (.net) that does not use iplimage but uses 
    list of byte[]
instead through c++/cli.
Any idea how to add/convert iplimage to the 
    list of byte[]   ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to store compressed image (jpg) or unpacked bitmap presentation (imageData)?

Comment: I want to store the Iplimage data.

Comment: That's not an answer.  Is `lplimage` a pointer to the unpacked image data starting at pixel `(0,0)` or is it a pointer to an entire image in memory which may very well be compressed, contain file headers, etc?  The two are very different.

Comment: I am using cvQueryframe to capture a frame from an Avi video and that frame is saved to an Iplimage pointer. I would assume the captured frame is compressed image but I am not sure

Comment: @bestnagi No image in iplImage is uncompressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to copy exact pixels from iplimage.imageData, you can use [Marshal.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146631.aspx)
to copy data from an `IntPtr` (imageData) to a managed array (byte[]).

But since imageData is uncompressed, you might want to use `imencode` or [`cvEncodeImage`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=#CvMat%2a%20cvEncodeImage%28const%20char%2a%20ext,%20const%20CvArr%2a%20image,%20const%20int%2a%20params%29) to compress it to a intermediate buffer and then copy that to a `byte[]` with above code.

Comment: I was first doing 
int img_sz1 = img1->width * img1->height * img1->nChannels;  array <Byte>^ hh1 = gcnew array<Byte> (img_sz1);  Marshal::Copy( (IntPtr)img->imageData, hh1, 0, img_sz1 );
and it was working.

I added the encoding step

CvMat* buf = cvEncodeImage(".jpeg", img1, jpeg_params);
img_sz1=buf->width*buf->height
Marshal::Copy( (IntPtr)buf, hh1, 0, img_sz1 );
and now it gives me the error at the marshal:copy line
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll. Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory.

Comment: The first approach was partially correct `image_sz1` should be `img1->height * img1->widthStep`. in the second approach your copying `cvMat` instead of its data `buf->ptr` (i guess). correct these two errors and let me now if its still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Before doing anything else, take the time to learn [how an `IplImage` is created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272005/working-with-real-time-data-bypassing-cvloadimage/11355217#11355217), and what kind of information it stores.

Then, notice that the pixels of the image can be accessed through the member `imageData`, which is an `unsigned char*`:

```
IplImage* image = cvLoadImage("starwars.jpg", 0);
int img_sz = image->width * image->height * image->nChannels;
unsigned char* data = (unsigned char*) malloc(img_sz);
memcopy(data, image->imageData, img_sz);
```

You'll have to do a similar procedure to convert it to `byte[]`. By the way, this post][2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187745/audio-output-with-video-processing-with-opencv/8191506#8191506) shows (among other things) how to convert an `IplImage*` to a `SDL_Surface*`.

Comment: Why do you copy data instead of using direct access? (it may take a long time when threre are many images)

Comment: The example above is only to demonstrate how one could use the IplImage to copy the pixels and create a new image.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would recommend that you switch to the C++ API of OpenCV if possible - it offers a lot more flexibility and features as compared to the old C interface.

In the C++ interface, a snippet to perform the above task would be:

```
cv::Mat image = cv::imread(imname);
uchar *ptr = (uchar*)image.data
```

You can use your ptr( an 8 bit unsigned byte data ) wherever you want - do remember that modifying this data will modify the actual image. If you do not want that to happen, take a copy of the data using memcpy.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you search something like this :

```
IplImage* image = cvLoadImage("image.bmp");
std::list<unsigned char*> bytes;
for (int i=0;i<image->height;i++)
 {
   bytes.push_back(image->imageData + image ->widthStep*i);
 }
```

you could test that this works doing the following (I access here the first pixel of the second row):

```
std::list<unsigned char*>::iterator it = bytes.begin();
it++;
*(*it) = 22;
int a = *((unsigned char*)(image->imageData + image->widthStep*1));
```

I didn t find no way to do things like this with the new cv::Mat object. You can transform the image to std::vectors but there is no way to transform the image to a row std::vector/std::list.
But if you remain use the cv::Mat class you can try the `cv::Ptr<Pixelformat>` that also gives access to the row pointers.